# Iphone html 5 app always prompt for share location on each page

Tags: iphone, ios, html, geolocation

I have an iphone app which is in html 5. Most pages need to know location of the app to give user data. The app prompts for "share location" on each page, even if the users allows to share the location. It will not prompt once the user has opened the same page a second time. Why does it always prompt for "share location" on every new page visited in the app?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing just the opposite in safari iphone 4 edition.  Once a user clicks 'share location' pop-up then it works ONCE.  The next time the user comes back to the page it doesn't share and there is no pop up and so the user can't even opt to share.

I tested this in android browser (samsung galaxy 2) and saw similar behavior.  My workaround was using the android firefox browser.  it worked just fine and would continue to share on subsequent returns to the page.  That's a lousy workaround because nobody uses firefox android edition.